# how can i limit the user by letting him input a number only if higher than minimum_range?

Tags: python, input, range, valueerror

```
import random


def input_range():
    minimum_range = 5
    users_range = input("set the maximum value for the range, minimum " + minimum_range + ":")
    if int(users_range) > int(minimum_range):
        print("The maximum range you selected is:", users_range)
    else:
        print("Out of range, try again")

    random_number = random.randint(int(minimum_range), int(users_range))
    print(random_number)


def name_user_request():
    users_name = input("what's yor name? ")
    print("Hi " + users_name + " nice to meet you")


input_range()
name_user_request()
```

this code i posted gives me an error if i input a number lower than minimum_range (in this case 5) any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a recursion !!

```
import random

def input_range():
    minimum_range = 5
    users_range = input("set the maximum value for the range, minimum " + str(minimum_range) + ":")
    if int(users_range) > int(minimum_range):
        print("The maximum range you selected is:", users_range)
        random_number = random.randint(int(minimum_range), int(users_range))
        print(random_number)
        return        
    else:
        print("Out of range, try again")
        input_range()
    return    



def name_user_request():
    users_name = input("what's yor name? ")
    print("Hi " + users_name + " nice to meet you")

input_range()
name_user_request()
```

Comment: your function was printing the message about "Out of range", but not taking any further action. By recursively calling the function, you make sure the user enters an appropriate value. In your implementation, when the code moves forward without an appropriate value, the random.randint breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop to ask for a valid input over and over again (I changed other lines to use f-strings):

```py
import random

def input_range():
    minimum_range = 5
    prompt = f"Set the maximum value for the range, minimum {minimum_range}: "

    while (users_range := int(input(prompt))) < minimum_range:
        print("Out of range, try again")
    print(f"The maximum range you selected is: {users_range}")

    random_number = random.randint(minimum_range, users_range)
    print(random_number)

def name_user_request():
    users_name = input("what's yor name? ")
    print(f"Hi {users_name}, nice to meet you!")

input_range()
name_user_request()
```

Note that it uses "walrus" operator `:=` (introduced in python 3.8). Without walrus operator, you can replace the `while` part with

```py
users_range = int(input(prompt))
while users_range < minimum_range:
    print("Out of range, try again")
    users_range = int(input(prompt))
```